# How to prevent a navbar from overlapping other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm working on building a website, and I have an issue where the navbar is hiding the first bit of the page so I can't see the information. How would I fix this? The link to my website is here:
    codepen.io/sookyungahn/pen/wzQkBp?editors=1100

Comment: Your code is where?

Comment: @GeoffJames Good day, I didn't paste the code because it was built in an IDE, if I am correct. I didn't want to paste the entire code, but is it better for me to do so? In that case I would need to include extra bits to do so.

Comment: You originally said "*Here is my code:*"... which is why I asked. Ever heard of "RTFM"? I would advise to read the documentation of something before you start to use it and come onto SO to ask an already common question... Anyway: You could set the `padding-top` of your body to be the same as what your navbar's height is to push the content down the right amount (see @Ranveer's answer below)

Comment: @GeoffJames Thanks, I tried your solution, but somehow it seems that my entire body element is pushed down causing the entire page to just shift down by x-pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, add `padding-top` in `home` div id with same size height on your nav bar.

```
<div class="container-fluid well" id="home" style="display:block; padding-top:50px;">
```

Comment: Good day, thank you! Your answer worked. Is it correct that it works because the navbar is 50px tall? Also, why wouldn't the previous answer work in my case?

Comment: Yes is it! If your navbar chage height, just change padding-top of your home div.

Comment: Thank you! I also want to ask, just for future use, what would I do if I wanted to make the padding (or even margin) increase or decrease part of the div?

For example, I create a div with a size of 1000*500. Then I add an element at the center of it and want it shifted down without adding to the div. If I use padding-top again, would that add to the div size? I do remember there was a specific code for it, but I just can't remember where I saw it.

Comment: if you want add padding without change size of the div, you can add this in your css element: `box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 1):

Add a padding of the size of your navbar's height to the body.

In the official bootstrap example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), they add a `70px` padding on top. Basically,

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 2017 add `position: sticky; top:0;` to navbar and it will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img style="margin-right:10px;margin-top:50px" class="image gap img-rounded pull-left" src="http://odezhda-stilnaya.ru/kartinki/1/ptichka_babochki_zvezdy_2560x1600.jpg" alt="PLACEHOLDER IMAGE" />
    <div>
      <h3 style="font-family:HelveticaNeue, Tahoma; font-weight:200;margin-top:50px;">I am a website developer, passionate about programming and assisting people. I am currently an intern at a tech startup.
      </h3>
```

Great Code:)

Just add margin-top:50px as shown.

Happy Coding :)